# Quarkus lazy initialize

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I am getting the following error whenever I try to return all records using the rest method.

Error:

Internal Server Error
Error handling e6059ae8-5970-4ac2-a1fa-7325768944bb-1, org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'task' from model.Board

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [model.Board.task] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session

first model

```
@Entity
public class Task{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TaskID")
    public Long taskId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BoardID")
    public Board board;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "Description", length = 1000)
    public String description;
}
```

second model

```
@Entity
public class Board{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BoardID")
    public Long boardId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board")
    public List<Task> task = new ArrayList<>();;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "Position")
    @NotNull
    public int position;
}
```

repository :

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional
public class BoardRepository implements PanacheRepository<Board> {
}
```

example REST method

```
@Transactional
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleResource {

    @Inject
    BoardRepository boardRepository;

    @Inject
    TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @GET
    @Transactional
    public List<Board> getAll() {
        return boardRepository.listAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is, that during JSON serialization, it tries to serialize the `task` list which has a back reference to `Board` and something in that graph might not be initialized. Also, the serialization could lead to a cycle which can't be modeled directly in JSON so you have to resolve this somehow.

- Use `@JsonIgnore` to exclude a field from JSON serialization
- Use a DTO, preferrably with [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for best performance which has a [Quarkus integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#quarkus-integration), that only models a subset of the state that you really want to expose